# Access queues from outside class

Tags: c++14

```
class abc{
    queue<string> Q;
    Q.push("Nomi");
};

class xyz{
    abc Obj;
    display()
    { cout << Obj.Q.front(); }  
};

int main()
{ 
    xyz Obj;
    Obj.display();
    return 0;
}
```

When I call display function, It doesn't print "Nomi" but is empty. I'm beginner with data structure. How can I access a queue of one class in other? Anything with pointers???

Comment: [This code doesn't compile](http://rextester.com/LAY2992), let alone run or print anything. `Q.push("Nomi");` line makes no sense where it is. Besides, `Q` is a private member of `abc`; `xyz::display` has no access to it. For that matter, xyz::display` is itself a private member, so `main` can't call it.

Comment: thanks but I've made the things public already in my code. I just showed the structure here. let make it like Q.push(x) (string x ) ; still it doesn't print the same. All I wanna know is why values in the queue disappear?

Comment: If you'd still like assistance, show the code that you are actually running, not some sketch of it. In other words, prepare a [mcve].